# preencher um array com indice

Tags: php, array

Eu possuo os seguinte *arrays*:

```php
$lista_geral= array(
    0|7897748704559 =>'',
    0|7897748704009 =>'',
    0|7897748705501 =>'', 
    0|7897748704160 =>'', 
    0|7897748704573 =>'', 
    0|7897748704238 =>'', 
    0|7897748705587 =>'', 
    0|7897748705556 =>'', 
    0|7897748704337 =>'',
    0|7897748704320 =>'', 
);
$lista_quantidade = array(150,10,6,12,45,50,5,25,3,2);
```

Quero pegar os valores do *array*(`$lista_geral`) e colocar em ordem no *array*(`$lista_quantidade`)
dessa forma:

```php
Array
(
    [0|7897748704559] => 150
    [0|7897748704009] => 10
    [0|7897748705501] => 6
    [0|7897748704160] => 12
    [0|7897748704573] => 45
    [0|7897748704238] => 50
    [0|7897748705587] => 5
    [0|7897748705556] => 25
    [0|7897748704337] => 3
    [0|7897748704320] => 2
)
```

Já tentei usar o `array_push` porem não funcionou, gostaria de alguma ajuda por favor.

Meu código:

```
foreach($lista_quantidade as $ListaQuantidade){
    array_push($lista_geral, $ListaQuantidade);
}
```

Comment: O `0|` do `0|7897748704160` deve sumir?

Comment: ele é irrelevante pode permanecer

Comment: se você tem acesso aos índices e sabe que eles sempre começam com `0|alguma_coisa`, você pode alterar o índice pra remover o `0|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um novo array e inserir a chave do primeiro com o valor do segundo:

```
$lista_geral= array(
    0|7897748704559 =>'',
    0|7897748704009 =>'',
    0|7897748705501 =>'', 
    0|7897748704160 =>'', 
    0|7897748704573 =>'', 
    0|7897748704238 =>'', 
    0|7897748705587 =>'', 
    0|7897748705556 =>'', 
    0|7897748704337 =>'',
    0|7897748704320 =>'', 
);
$lista_quantidade = array(150,10,6,12,45,50,5,25,3,2);

$lista_nova = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($lista_geral as $chave => $valor){
    $lista_nova[$chave] = $lista_quantidade[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente, grato!.